# HTTP Status 404 - Not Found Glassfish on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, aero-glass

Im beginner in the java, and im working with some small project. I have a problem. When i want to go through the link to open a JSP page with some method i got this error:

HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
type Status report
messageNot Found
descriptionThe requested resource is not available.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1

(books.jsp is in "pages" directory.)

thank you guys.

Here is my code:
this is the link code:

**

```
<div class="left_bar">
    <h4>Genres:</h4>
    <ul class="nav">
        <jsp:useBean id="genreList" class="ua.web.first.GenreList" scope="application"/>
        <%
            for (Genre genre : genreList.getGenreList()) {
        %>
        <li><a href="../../pages/books.jsp?genre_id=<%=genre.getId()%>&name=<%=genre.getName()%>"><%=genre.getName()%></a></li>
        <%}%>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**

and here is the books.jsp:

```
<%@include file="../WEB-INF/jspf/left_bar.jspf" %>
<%request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    long genreId = 0L;
    try {
        genreId = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("genre_id"));
    } catch (Exception exception1) {
        System.out.println("error");
        exception1.printStackTrace();
    }
%>

<jsp:useBean id="bookList" class="ua.web.first.BookList" scope="page"/>

<dic class="book_list">
    <h3><%request.getParameter("name");%></h3>
    <table cellpadding="30" style="font-size: 12px">

        <%
            for (Book book : bookList.getBooksByGenre(genreId)) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:400px; height: 100px;">
                <p style="color:blueviolet; font-weight: bold;font-size: 15px;"><% book.getName();%></p>
                <br><strong>Isbn:</strong> <% book.getIsbn(); %>
                <br><strong>Publisher</strong> <% book.getPublisher();%>
                <br><strong>Page count</strong> <% book.getPageCount(); %>
                <br><strong>Publish year</strong><% book.getDate(); %>
                <br><strong>Author</strong> <% book.getAuthor(); %>
                <p style="margin: 10px;"><a href="#">Read</a></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 150px; height: 100px">
                image
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%}%>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: How about your index.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

my index.jsp is not finished, but it works

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <div class="index_conteiner">
            <p class="text">Welcome to our library</p>
             <form class="form" action="pages/main.jsp" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="30" />
            <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```